# get value of each tag li in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, tags, html-lists

I have ASP.NET MVC 5 project and I have some tag li and I want when I click each tag get value of this in jquery
So I write some code which I can not get value of them and 
I use below code but I can not get result please correct me

```
@model IEnumerable<Sportcup.Models.news>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script>
    function f2() {

        var ID = $('#mID').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/GetNext",
                    data: { param: ID},
                    type:"post",
                    success: function (value) {
                         results = JSON.parse(value);
                        $("#mydiv").empty();
                        $.each(results, function (idx, result) {
                        })
                    }
                })
      }
</script>

    @{ int c=Model.Count() / 4;}
<ul class="pagination no-margin">
    <li><a href="~/Home/GetLast?ID=@Model.Count()/4">«</a></li>
   @for (int i = 1; i <= Model.Count() / 4; i++)
   {
       if (TempData["ID"] != null && i == int.Parse(TempData["ID"].ToString()))
       {
         <li class="active"><a href="javascript:f2()">@i</a></li>   
         <li><input type="hidden" id="mID" name="ID" value="@i"/></li>
       }
       else
       {

        <li><a href="javascript:f2()">@i</a></li>
        <li><input type="hidden" id="mID" name="ID" value="@i" /></li>
       }
   }
    <li><a href="~/Home/GetLast?ID=@c">»</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that `id` attribute must be unique so if put this in `for` loop it will not work..

You have 2 options:

1. Pass the `value` to the function `f2` like:

   ```
   <a href="javascript:f2(@i)">@i</a>
   ```

   Then in the `f2` function define:

   ```
   function f2(value) {
   ```
2. If you must to use `:hidden` input, you can pass the `this` (the link) input the function, then find the `:hidden` right after it. Like:

   ```
   <a href="javascript:f2(this)">@i</a>
   ```

   Then in `f2()` function:

   ```
   function f2(elm) {
      var value = $(elm).parent().next().find(':hidden').val();
      //.. the rest of the code.
   ```